# addResponseInterceptor in restangular controller

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm pretty new with AngularJS and I'm trying to use restangular to call my server Rest API that returns me this json:

```
{"Users":[{"AN01_ID":1,"AN01_NAME":"cust1","AN01_REF":1,"AN01_ALT":4},{"AN01_ID":2,"AN01_NAME":"cust2","AN01_REF":2,"AN01_ALT":3},{"AN01_ID":3,"AN01_NAME":"cust3","AN01_REF":3,"AN01_ALT":2},{"AN01_ID":4,"AN01_NAME":"cust4","AN01_REF":4,"AN01_ALT":1}],"ResponseStatus":{}}
```

from what I've read in the docs I need to set the `addResponseInterceptor` in `config` to extract the array I need from my json response like this:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['restangular']);

app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://myserver/api/');

  RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
    return data.Users;
  });
});

app.controller('usersController', function($scope, Restangular) {
    $scope.users = Restangular.all('users.json').getList().$object;
});
```

My question is: if I need to specify a different array name for each controller, how can I define the `addResponseInterceptor` in my controllers (or alternatively: how can I extract specific array in my controllers)?

Comment: The what parameter will let you see what resource you are requesting in each restangular call, so you use that to do a switch in whatever logic you want to write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the common way of using `responseInterceptor`, you should do some generic things in interceptor like some attribute you want to put every response.

For extracting specific response you should always use promise callback and resolve response in your then block, so this should be your code.

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['restangular']);

app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://myserver/api/');
  // remove this part of the code as you do not need it
});

app.controller('usersController', function($scope, Restangular) {
    Restangular.all('users.json').getList().then(function(response){
        $scope.users = response.Users;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed this is the way I would take... I've tried your example but I always get the error: "Error: Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or something else".

Comment: @wizzy in your case actually you are getting an object from your response so you should call get instead of getList...

Comment: yeah... I've tried it too but I can't understand why it doesn't works. I created a plunks here: http://plnkr.co/edit/DN4p5kKohuEvwPvt8MtK from the Chrome console I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"

Comment: @wizzy just convert all to one and you should be okay... Restangular.one(...).get()